# Delaying $ajax calls after certain code completes executing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get geolocation data and then incorporate that data into the $ajax call URL. But what happens is that, both console.log(lat/lon) calls return the initial value (0). Which means that the geolocation call is too late to return and the $ajax calls are simply made with default values as in: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=0&lon=0&appid=9011468f93d0dac073b28cda9e83cd01"

```
var lat = 0;
var lon = 0;

console.log(lat);
console.log(lon);

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    lon = pos.coords.longitude;
  })
}

function getWeatherData() {
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lon);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=9011468f93d0dac073b28cda9e83cd01",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);

    },
    error: function () {
      console.log("REKT");
    }
  })
}, 1000);
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
    getWeatherData();
  });
```

I solved it by adding an arbitrary timeout function to the $ajax call, but what if the call takes more than 1000 or 10000ms to return?
So, my question would be is there a more elegant solution to make $ajax call ONLY when the geolocation code finishes executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the call to the callback of getCurrentPosition

Added value: it does not call the getWeatherData if the geolocation is not existing. Right now you always call it

```
$(function() { 
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){ 
     lat = pos.coords.latitude; 
     lon = pos.coords.longitude; 
     getWeatherData(); 
   });
  }
});
```

Also this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: I chose this as the answer simply because it was a more modular solution.

I tried writing some code just to take a closer look at the data flow: http://pastebin.com/1w2fiXz8

So, even though "Initializing..." fires first, "Success!" is only logged after "Launching getWeatherData". I'm a bit new at coding, but according to this: the callback function is called, and until it, well, calls back (hence the name), other code is continued to be executed. "Success!" is executed only when the function calls back?  In conclusion, callback functions are asynchronous by nature?

Comment: They are THE conclusion of an async call.

Answer (score 1):

Call your `ajax` function in the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

```js
var lat = 0;
var lon = 0;

function getWeatherData(){

   if (navigator.geolocation) {

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
        lat = pos.coords.latitude;
        lon = pos.coords.longitude;
    
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon +     "&appid=9011468f93d0dac073b28cda9e83cd01",
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function () {
            console.log("REKT");
          }
        });
    });
   }
 }
                                           

 $(document).ready(function () {
    getWeatherData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but you will see an error in Google Chrome

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS

You can see here [**Google Insecure origins**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)